# Anyone know a way for me to remove the recursion from this code im having problems doing it

Tags: arrays, c, recursion, search, binary

i just want it to work without the recursion elements its doing binary search in arrays
and i don't know a way to remove recursion succesfully

```
#include <stdio.h>


int busca(int vet[], int n, int e, int d)
{
    if(d >= e){
        int m = (e + d)/2;
        if(vet[m] == n){
            return m;
        }
        if(vet[m] < n){
            return busca(vet, n, m+1, d); 
        }
        if(vet[m] > n){
            return busca(vet, n, e, m-1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

void ordena(int vet[]){
    int i, j, temp;
    for( i=0; i<4; i++ ){
        for( j=i+1; j<4; j++ ){
            if( vet[i] > vet[j] ){
                temp    = vet[i];
                vet[i] = vet[j];
                vet[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int tam, b, i;
    printf("Tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &tam);
    
    int vet[tam];
    for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
        printf("elemento %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
    }
    
    ordena(vet);
    
    printf("informe o que busca: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    
    int r = busca(vet, b, 0, tam-1);
    if(r == -1){
        printf("%d.\n", r);
        printf("\nAusente.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("%d presente na posicao %d.\n", b, r+1);
    }
}
```

Just simples binary search in arrays its working fine but i want it without the recursion parts

Answer (score 0):

Each call is tail recursive (`return busca( ... )`), so it's quite easy. Instead of making the call, set the parameters to the arguments for the call, then jump to the start of the function.

In other words, replace

```c
return busca(vet, n, m+1, d);
```

```c
return busca(vet, n, e, m-1);
```

with

```c
vet = vet;
n   = n;
e   = m+1;
d   = d;
goto START_OF_FUNCTION;
```

```c
vet = vet;
n   = n;
e   = e;
d   = m-1;
goto START_OF_FUNCTION;
```

Cleaned up, it looks like this.

```c
int busca( int vet[], int n, int e, int d ) {
    while ( e <= d ) {
        int m = ( e + d ) / 2;
        if ( vet[m] == n ) {
            return m;
        }

        if ( vet[m] < n ) {
            e = m + 1;
        } else {
            d = m - 1;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

---

By the way, I'd change the interface so that `d` is the index after the last one.

```c
int busca( int vet[], int n, int e, int d ) {
    while ( e < d ) {                // <---
        int m = ( e + d ) / 2;
        if ( vet[m] == n ) {
            return m;
        }

        if ( vet[m] < n ) {
            e = m + 1;
        } else {
            d = m;                   // <---
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

That way, we simply pass the size instead of size-1.

```c
int r = busca( vet, b, 0, tam );
```